# Как правильно сделать дженерную функцию `getCallFrom`?

Tags: kotlin, generics

```
class MyClass {
    
    // Функция для получения запроса ApolloQueryCall из Query
    fun getCallFrom(query: Query<*, *, *>): ApolloQueryCall<out Any?> = apolloClient.query(query)

    // Функция для тестирования
    fun test() {
        // Первый запрос с ожиданием ответа типа com.apollographql.apollo.api.Response<MyTestQuery.Data>
        val response1: com.apollographql.apollo.api.Response<MyTestQuery.Data> = apolloClient.query(
            MyTestQuery("test")
        ).await()
        
        // Второй запрос, использующий вашу общую функцию
        // Проблема в том, что вам нужно получить тот же тип результата, что и response1
        val response2: com.apollographql.apollo.api.Response<out Any?> = getCallFrom(
            MyTestQuery("test")
        ).await()
    }
}
```

В функции `test()` два ответа (`response1` и `response2`) с различием в возвращающем типе. Для первого использован `appoloClient.query`, а для второго - моя общая функция `getCallFrom`.

Мне нужно получить такой же тип результата из моей общей функции, как и в `response1` (com.apollographql.apollo.api.Response<MyTestQuery.Data>).

Я попробовал разные способы передачи типов (вместо *), но это не работает.

Что делаю не так?

Comment: Пробовали параметризировать метод `getCallFrom`? Например, так: `fun <T, U, V> getCallFrom(query: Query<T, U, V>): ApolloQueryCall<V> = ...` Из вопроса не совсем ясно, что такое тип `Query<*, *, *>` (с тремя параметрами-типами), откуда он, из какой библиотеки? Укажите в вопросе, какую именно библиотеку вы используете. Я нашел в документации интерфейс [`Query<D : Data>`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/kotlin/kdoc/apollo-api/com.apollographql.apollo3.api/-query/index.html), у которого только один параметр-тип.

Comment: @VadikSirekanyan Да, это помогло, в итоге функция выглядит так - `private fun<X: Operation.Data, Y, Z: Operation.Variables> getCallFrom(query: Query<X, Y, Z>): ApolloQueryCall<Y>? = apolloClient.query(query)`. Библиотека которая использовалась `apollo`. Можете сделать комментарий ответом, чтоб я мог принять его?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По всей видимости, вам нужно параметризировать метод `getCallFrom`. Укажите параметры-типы в угловых скобках после ключевого слова `fun`. Получится примерно следующее:

```
fun <T, U, V> getCallFrom(query: Query<T, U, V>): ApolloQueryCall<U> {
    ...
}
```